# Shopware 5 : Wrong format release date in API order data

Tags: api, shopware, shopware5

When I try to retrieve shopware order data using API, We are getting release date as `"releaseDate": "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0053",`
I have checked in shopware 5 and shopware 6, both have the same issue, while checked in the admin panel product but the release date is not set still we are receiving.

Comment: I can not reproduce that on SW5. Tested with a past and future date. Do you have some different timezones set on your DB server than your app server?

Comment: Can you please try to get order data using api where on the details as like below.
"details": [{
  "releaseDate": "-0001-11-30T00:00:00+0100",

you will find releaseDate as suggested.. getting this broken date from last much time..

Comment: Can you check the release data of your order directly in the SQL database? it might be "0" already there. Please post a screenshot of an excerpt of the order database table.